# How to set isolation level

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I want to set isolation level to `repeatable read`. How do I achieve this using gorm orm for postgres.

Example code:

```
func CreateAnimals(db *gorm.DB) err {
  tx := db.Begin()
  // Note the use of tx as the database handle once you are within a transaction

  if err := tx.Create(&Animal{Name: "Giraffe"}).Error; err != nil {
     tx.Rollback()
     return err
  }

  if err := tx.Create(&Animal{Name: "Lion"}).Error; err != nil {
     tx.Rollback()
     return err
  }

  tx.Commit()
  return nil
}
```

Comment: Your title just says "GORM" but isn't this entirely dependant on the database driver being used? E.g. for PostgreSQL you'd either have to configure the default database connect settings, execute a [`SET TRANSACTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-set-transaction.html) command, or see if the specific Go PostgreSQL driver you are using (there is more than one) exposes this directly.

Comment: Sure enough, [`DB.Begin`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Begin) (which is what GORM uses) says "The isolation level is dependent on the driver." Searching `github.com/lib/pq` (you didn't say which driver you were using) gives some advice in [issue 261](https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/261).

Comment: Yes, I am using the `github.com/lib/pq` driver. Thank you! The issue answers my question, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem [here](https://github.com/AlexAtNet/vega/blob/master/src/vega/content/model.go#L104):

```
func GetPageAfterUpdate(dp model.DbProvider, id int, update int, page *Page) (err error) {
  tx := dp.DB().Begin()

  err = tx.Exec(`set transaction isolation level repeatable read`).Error
  if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return
  }
```

And it is exactly gorm with pg.