# Force a "lock" with Postgres and GO

Tags: postgresql, go, locking, load-generator

I am new to Postgres so this may be obvious (or very difficult, I am not sure).

I would like to force a table or row to be "locked" for at least a few seconds at a time. Which will cause a second operation to "wait".

I am using golang with "github.com/lib/pq" to interact with the database.

The reason I need this is because I am working on a project that monitors postgresql. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Set the transaction isolation level to serializable https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-transaction.html

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31845051/6069012) answer is very similar to what you want. Just use whatever isolation level is necessary.

Comment: @Hackerman Well, that worked nicely.

Comment: The OP just has to keep in mind that setting that isolation level is an overhead to the server....more secure -> less performance...that's the way it works .

Comment: overhead is fine, I just need a situation where queries are blocked due to a lock. Thanks, I will try the suggestions!

Comment: Also there's a chance of another transaction failing due to serialization errors. You may want to use "select for update" as well. And be prepared to retry transactions that fail due to serialization errors.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use select ... for update to lock a row or rows for the length of the transaction.

Basically, it's like:

```
begin;
select * from foo where quatloos = 100 for update;
update foo set feens = feens + 1 where quatloos = 100;
commit;
```

This will execute an exclusive row-level lock on foo table rows where quatloos = 100. Any other transaction attempting to access those rows will be blocked until commit or rollback has been issued once the select for update has run.

Ideally, these locks should live as short as possible.

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html